# Java Eclipse WindowsBuilder: me dice que cambie mis textfield y checkbox a final pero, el error no desaparece

Tags: java

El programa dice que cambie todos mis textfield y checkbox a "final" pero, cuando lo hago, en otra parte del codigo me indica que debo remover "final", estoy confundido.

el error al comienzo lo marca aquí:

```
JButton btnCalcular = new JButton("Calcular");
        btnCalcular.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                // Si es Llamada Local
                if (checkboxLocal.isSelected())
                {
                }

                // Si es Llamada Provincial y Franja 1
                else if (checkboxProvincial.isSelected() && checkboxFranja1.isSelected())
                {
                }

                // Si es Llamada Provincial y Franja 2
                else if (checkboxProvincial.isSelected() && checkboxFranja2.isSelected())
                {
                }

                // Si es Llamada Provincial y Franja 3
                else if (checkboxProvincial.isSelected() && checkboxFranja3.isSelected())
                {
                }
            }
        });
```

El error es:

> Cannot refer to the non-final local variable txtNumeroOrigen defined
>   in an enclosing scope

Este error aparece en las siguientes cosas:

```
                txtNumeroOrigen.setText("");
                txtNumeroDestino.setText("");
                txtDuracion.setText("");

                // Check Box
                checkboxProvincial.setSelected(false);
                checkboxProvincial.setEnabled(true);
                checkboxLocal.setSelected(false);
                checkboxLocal.setEnabled(true);
                checkboxFranja1.setSelected(false);
                checkboxFranja2.setSelected(false);
                checkboxFranja3.setSelected(false);
                checkboxFranja1.setEnabled(false);
                checkboxFranja2.setEnabled(false);
                checkboxFranja3.setEnabled(false);
```

Qué estoy haciendo mal?, estoy declarando las cosas donde no es?.
Dice que ponga final y después que lo quite, no entiendo nada.

Comment: He escrito una respuesta, pero luego he repasado tu perfil y he comprobado que no te molestas en marcar como correctas las respuestas que te dan, ni las votas, etc., así que prefiero borrarla hasta que aprendas como funciona el sitio. Un saludo.

Comment: Hola, tienes toda la razón, se me ha olvidado seleccionar la respuesta a mi pregunta. Lo he arreglado y también he dado mi voto en mis preguntas mas viejas. Aún tengo una por resolver y esperando por la respuesta de la persona en el topic, por esta razón aún la dejo sin marcar una respuesta como final.

Perdóname, de igual forma te pido que reconsideres tu decisión y puedas ayudarme con este tema, estoy aprendiendo Java con WindowsBuilder y gracias a ustedes he podido echar adelante.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay dos cuestiones aquí:

- Para acceder a una variable local desde una clase anónima, la variable debe ser `final`. Es un problema causado porque Java no implementa *closures*, y hace un "apaño" permitiendo acceder a variables locales `final`<sup>1</sup>
- Si una variable es `final`, no se le pueden asignar valores después de la declaración.

Tú añades el `final` para solucionar el primer problema, y te encuentras con el segundo.

La solución es obvia:

```
final JCheckBox checkboxProvincial = new JCheckBox("Provincial");
```

y no asignar nunca un nuevo objeto a `checkboxProvincial`. Repetir para el resto de variables.

---

<sup>1</sup>Lo que hace Java es aprovechar que el valor de la variable no va a cambiar (porque es `final`) para hacer una "copia" de la referencia en la clase anónima.

Comment: Hola, he agregado final a todas las declaraciones al comienzo del programa pero, al hacerlo con checkboxProvincial y demás, me sale un error diciendo: Duplicate local variable checkboxProvincial, y me sugiere que: Rename checkboxProvincial. La verdad que no se como solucionarlo, por cierto gracias por tratar de ayudarme.

Comment: Significa que has definido dos variables con el nombre `checkboxProvincial`.

Comment: Entonces como podría arreglarlo?, tengo al comienzo, por mencionar una, esto: JCheckBox checkboxProvincial = null;, luego mas abajo tengo esto: checkboxProvincial = new JCheckBox("Provincial"); que debo cambiar para que el nombre de la variable no sea repetida?, a lo mejor es facil para ti pero, para mi no lo es, es mi primera vez y estoy comenzando a entender el por qué de las cosas. Espero no sea mucha molestia echarme otra mano.

Comment: Te comparto el código completo, para que puedas ver mejor si estoy haciendo las cosas mal. Estoy confundido de qué es lo correcto, si declarar todo junto al comienzo o dejar todo para declararlo cuando se necesiten las cosas. Espero puedas ayudarme, codigo: https://codeshare.io/ayqYla

Comment: **NO** voy a revisar tu código completo, aquí estamos para ayudar con problemas **concretos** y que aprendas; no para hacer tu trabajo. Como he dicho más arriba, el error es porque has definido dos variables con el mismo nombre (o la misma variable dos veces, como prefieras definirlo); así que una de ellas sobra. Igual convendría que empezaras a programar con un ejemplo más sencillo.

Comment: Hola, el problema es que al remover la 1era declaracion, me marca error en la 2d, y viceversa. Podría indicarme cual es el lugar correcto para declararlo y cual es la forma correcta de asignarle un nombre?. Es así?: JCheckBox checkboxProvincial, luego abajo en el codigo: checkboxProvincial = JCheckBox("Provincial"). Espero puedas ayudarme por favor, no he logrado resolver la duda del problema original.

Comment: En el código que has enlazado sólo hay una declaración de cada checkbox. No están declarados como `final`, así que el error inicial seguirá apareciendo. Aparte de eso ¿que error da?

Comment: Hola, he puesto final nuevamente en todos los checkbox, al comienzo del programa, ejemplo: final JCheckBox checkboxProvincial = new JCheckBox("Provincial");. Pero, ahora en todos los textfield me indica que debo inicializarlos, cuando los pongo null, me tira otro error en los textfield diciendo: Null pointer access: The variable ...... can only be null at this location. Remuevo entonces el null al comienzo del programa pero, siguen los errores, es como un ciclo. No se qué hacer. Tengo al comienzo: JTextField txtTotalDeLlamadas = null;

Comment: Pues inicialízalos con algo que no sea `null`... creando instancias de `JTextField`, por ejemplo...

Comment: He borrado todo y he comenzado de nuevo, ya que el error no desaparece. Estoy seguro que he colocado las cosas en mal sitio. Dejaré que Eclipse los ubique por mí. Tendré en cuenta tus consejos, muchas gracias hermano.

Comment: al parecer todo estaba bien localizado, se me ha presentado el error nuevamente. No podrías decirme qué es lo correcto para declarar un checkbox por ejemplo y qué codigo se usa para poder usarlos mas abajo en el codigo para asignarle un nombre?, al hacer esto, segun he aprendido, estos checkbox dentro de un actionperformer presentan el error, dicen que inicialize la variable, luego que lo quite, el programa me tiene loco, por favor ayudame, no sea tan duro conmigo, trato de aprender.

Comment: por favor, te he pegado un pedacito del codigo donde presento el problema.